# attributes and constructors in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and don't even know if this is the correct way of solving my situation.

I have a "Club" ActiveRecords model which has a "has_many" association to a "Member" model. I want the logged in "Club" to only be able to administrate it's own "Member" so in the beginning of each action in the "Member" model I did something similar to the following:

```
def index
 @members = Club.find(session[:club_id]).members
```

to access the right members. This did not however turn out very DRY as I did the same in every action. So I thought of using something equivalent to what would be called a constructor in other languages. The initialize method as I've understood it. This was however not working, [this](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html) told me why, and proposed an alternative. The after_initialize.

```
def after_initialize
 @club = Club.find(session[:club_id])
end

def index
 @members = @club.members
....
```

does not seem to work anyway. Any pointers to why?

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.members
```

Makes me think that the @club var isn't set at all.

Also, is this solution really a good one? This makes it hard to implement any kind of "super admin" who can manage the members in all of the clubs. Any ideas on where I am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a before_filter.
Define the filter in your ApplicationController (so that you can access it from any controller).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # ..

  protected

    def load_members
      @members = if session[:club_id]
        Club.find(session[:club_id]).members
      else
        []
      end
    end

end
```

Then, load the filter before any action where you need it.
For example

```
class ClubController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_members, :only => %w( index )

  def index
    # here @members is set
  end
end
```

Otherwise, use lazy loading. You can use the same `load_members` and call it whenever you need it.

```
class ClubController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # do something with members
    load_members.each { ... }
  end
end
```

Of course, you can customize `load_member` to raise an exception, redirect the client if `@members.empty?` or do whatever you want.

Comment: Great response. Exactly what I was looking for. One thing which I don't get though is the second parameter in the before_filter. Could you clarify the ":only => %w( index )" part?

Comment: The :only options specifies the filter should be performed only for the index action.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a [before_filter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) for this.

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_club

  def index
    @members = @club.members
  end

  private

    def find_club
      @club = Club.find(session[:club_id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of a plugin called Rolerequirement.  It allows you to make custom roles and apply them by controller: http://code.google.com/p/rolerequirement/